# AWS Codedeploy fails with JAVA_HOME error

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Have installed java 8 and

> Java -version

yields

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Having a AfterInstall script under hooks which simply has

```
cd $HOME/workspace
mvn clean install
```

AWS codedeploy is failing with following error

```
{\"message\":\"Script at specified location: scripts/start failed with exit code 1\",\"log\":\"LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall\\nScript - scripts/start\\n[stderr]Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.\\n[stderr]  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java\\n\"}"}
```

echo $JAVA_HOME gives

> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre

Have also tried setting JAVA_HOME to

> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45

When i try mvn clean install directly in the workspace it was able to pickup the Java correctly. Any idea what went wrong in code deploy?

```
hooks:   
        BeforeInstall:
        - location: scripts/pre_processing   
        AfterInstall: 
        - location: scripts/start
```

Comment: can you share your pom file and make sure you do not have any <executable> tag that points to the /usr/lib/jvm

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Please have a look i don't see any executable tag https://codeshare.io/4M1EZ

Answer (score 1):

- Codedeploy seems works fine, it just run whatever script you gave.
- This could be a problem of JAVA_HOME not accessible by current running user.
- If you don't specify the runas parameter inside the appSpec, the scripts will run under root privilege by default(since the host agent starts with root privilege).
- If this is the case, the possible workaround is either make JAVA_HOME accessible by root, or specify runas inside the appSpec for the AfterInstall script.

Comment: Have set JAVA_HOME inside root ~/.bash_profile as well as ec2User the problem persists.

Comment: You will have to put it in /etc/profile for it to actually be picked up. bash isn't involved here.

Comment: @JonathanTurpie  solution required me to reboot the instance , and it finally worked. (adding to /etc/profile), thanks a lot!